# Setting BasicFilter condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am not able to pass a variable to 'myConditionValue" for text_contains.

```
var myCondition = {
  "type": "TEXT_CONTAINS",
  "userEnteredValue": myConditionValue
};       

var columnIndex = 3;
filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] = {
  'condition': myCondition
}

var request = {
  "setBasicFilter": {
    "filter": filterSettings
  }
};
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
```

This other condition works just fine. I just need that "D" to come from a variable.

```
var myCondition = {
  "type": "TEXT_CONTAINS",
  "values": [{"userEnteredValue": "D"}]
};
```

Thank you in advance!
Agam

Comment: Try myCondition.values[0].userEnteredValue = variable;

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I was using a variable tied to:

```
range.getValues()
```

instead of

```
range.getValue()
```

It works now.

Thank you.